# Session getting destroyed on new page view

Tags: php, session, session-variables

Upon successful login, I'm saving the session variable.

When the user goes to different pages in the app, the session is gone even though I didn't explicitly destroy the session. How do i fix this?

Here is a page where the session appears to disappear.

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';
include 'core/sendmessage.php';
$user_info = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$getUser = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = ".$uid);

$user_info = array();

while($currentRow = mysql_fetch_array($getUser)){
    $user_info['firstname'] = $currentRow['first_name'];
    $user_info['lastname'] = $currentRow['last_name'];
    $user_info['username'] = $currentRow['username'];
}
?>
```

Within `core/init.php` I have the session start method.

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'database/connect.php';
require 'functions/users.php';
require 'functions/general.php';

if (logged_in() === true) { 
$user_data = user_data($_SESSION['user_id'],'first_name','last_name','username');
}

$errors = array();
?>
```

Comment: do you have `session_start()` at the top of each page?

Comment: Are you using `session_start();` at the beginning of every PHP script to initialize the sessions?

Comment: yes of course i am, i'll throw up some code now.

Comment: that would be helpful! p.s., always post your code here to start with. I'm not visiting some unknown URL to view unknown code

Comment: May I ask what the `logged_in()` function does? And if possible, could you show the function please? Thank you.
Try printing the `$_SESSION['user_id'];` like this: `echo "$_SESSION['user_id']";` and if the session shows up then that means that the sessions are fine still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> session_start() creates a session or **resumes** the current one based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or
>   passed via a cookie. (Visit **[PHP: session_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)**)

Add `session_start()` on the beginning of each page (after your `<?php` tag).

In your case:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start(); //--> ADD this line

include 'core/init.php';
include 'core/sendmessage.php';
$user_info = $_SESSION['user_id'];

...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try using a different name for all of this, since I don't think that it's great practice to use the value you are using for a session for another value (since that will replace your old value) and make the session disappear the next time you visit that page. A session only gets created once.

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';
include 'core/sendmessage.php';
$user_info = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$getUser = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = ".$uid);

$userinfo = array(); //I changed $user_info to $userinfo so it doesn't get mixed with the session.

while($currentRow = mysql_fetch_array($getUser)){
    //I removed the underscore
    $userinfo['firstname'] = $currentRow['first_name'];
    $userinfo['lastname'] = $currentRow['last_name'];
    $userinfo['username'] = $currentRow['username'];
}
?>
```

It should be fine by now, even though I haven't tested it.
I just changed the array to `$userinfo` so you can still use the session at all times without having it mixed with something.

Comment: this does nothing unfortunatley.

Comment: May I also ask where you are getting the `$uid` value from? If the value is null then the query won't work at all, meaning that you won't be able to retrieve the information from the database as you're trying to do inside the `while()`.